# underscore javascript _.each loop for properties nested array

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Hi Javascript/underscore gurus..

Lets say I receive a json object from the server which has an anonymous array nested as one of its properties... how would i loop through that array in an underscore _.each method?

This is my json object:

```
  "onlineUsers": [
    {
      "Id": "users/2",
      "Name": "Hamish",
      "LatestActivity": "2013-01-17T04:02:14.2113433Z",
      "LatestHeartbeat": "2013-01-17T04:02:14.2113433Z"
    },
    {
      "Id": "users/3",
      "Name": "Ken",
      "LatestActivity": "2013-01-17T03:45:20.066Z",
      "LatestHeartbeat": "2013-01-17T04:04:34.711Z"
    }
  ]
```

how would I modify this function to print out the names?

```
_.each(onlineUsers, function(user){log(user.name);});
```

This is printing out the actual collection of nested objects, obviously because they are elements in the nested array of onlineUsers... not sure how to get to that array to loop if it is anonymously passed in...

Thanks,
Hamish.

Comment: removing the outer `{}` should make it valid JSON.

Comment: At a minimum, the inner objects should be {name: 'Joe'},{name: 'bloggs'}. That alone makes it an invalid object and throws a JS error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JSON you are receiving from the server is invalid JSON. The array needs a property name, eg:

```
onlineUsers = { names: [{name : "Joe"}, {name : "bloggs"}]}
```

Then you could do this:

```
_.each(onlineUsers.names, function(user){log(user.name);});
```

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous array inside an object is not valid json, so you wouldn't be able to parse it.

either give the array a name or remove the outer object.